# How can I rewrite/redirect the default page in Meteor to point to /public/index.html

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-up

I am using `Meteor` as the backend to my `ionic+angular` webApp. I'm deploying the app using `meteor-up`. I have put my entire app in the `Meteor` `/public` folder and it works find when I access it like this:

`http://localhost:3000/index.html`

How can I set/rewrite/redirect the `Meteor` default page so I can load the same page from:

`http://localhost:3000/` or `http://localhost:3000/myApp`

without losing my `Meteor` server

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution:

```
fs = Npm.require('fs');
crypto = Npm.require('crypto');
WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/", function(req, res, next) {
  var data, filepath;
  if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    return next();
  }
  filepath = process.env.PWD + '/public/index.html';

  // serve default file, with eTag, 
  // i.e. http://localhost:3000/
  fs.readFile(filepath, function(err, buf) {
    var eTag;
    eTag = crypto.createHash('md5').update(buf).digest('hex');
    if (req.headers['if-none-match'] === eTag) {
      res.writeHead(304, 'Not Modified');
      return res.end();
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'ETag': eTag,
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    return res.end(buf);
  });
  return;

  // serve default file, without eTag or caching headers
  // i.e. http://localhost:3000/
  data = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
  });
  res.write(data);
  return res.end();

  // redirect to default file
  // i.e. http://localhost:3000/index.html
  res.writeHead(301, {
    'Location': '/index.html'
  });
  return res.end();
});
```