# How can I fs.readFile() a file from the /public folder of a meteor-up deployment?

Tags: node.js, meteor, fs, meteor-up

I have a `meteor-up/mupx` deployment with a page in the Meteor `/public` folder, `./public/index.html`

I can load the page successfully from a url that is something like this:

`http://my-app.com:3333/index.html`

But I would like to make this page the default page for the domain, so I can access it like this:

`http://my-app.com:3333/`

I added the following in my Meteor `bootstrap.js` file

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/", function(req, res, next) {
  var err, error, error1, filepath0, filepath1;
  if (req.originalUrl !== '/' || req.method !== 'GET') {
    return next();
  }
  try {
    filepath0 = process.env.PWD + '/public/index.html';
    // filepath1 = '/opt/my-app/current/bundle/programs/web.browser/app/index.html';
    fs.statSync(filepath0).isFile();
  } catch (error) {
      err = error1;
      console.log("file not available, path=" + filepath);
      return next();
  }
  fs.readFile(filepath0, function(err, buf) {
    var eTag, err, headers;
    try {
      eTag = crypto.createHash('md5').update(buf).digest('hex');
      if (req.headers['if-none-match'] === eTag) {
        res.writeHead(304, 'Not Modified');
        return res.end();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      eTag = null;
    }
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      'ETag': etag
    };
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    return res.end(buf);
  });
});
```

This works fine from my standard Meteor project. But when I deploy via `mupx` I get an exception because the `index.html` file is not in the same location.

How can I `fs.readFile()` the file which was located in `/path/to/Meteor/public` after it has been deployed via `mupx`

from `Meteor`, I could use `filepath0 = process.env.PWD + '/public/index.html'

But the same code from `mupx` gives `filepath0 = /bundle/bundle/public/index.html`, and the file is not there.

from the `mupx` server, I can actually `ls` the file at `filepath1`, but even using that value does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IronRouter has server side routes. see h/t [Serving an "index.html" file in public/ when using MeteorJS and Iron Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871590/serving-an-index-html-file-in-public-when-using-meteorjs-and-iron-router)

This is what I did to make it work:

setup files:

```
# copy /path/to/ionic/www to /path/to/meteor/public
# put ./public/index.html into ./private
cd /path/to/meteor/private; ln -s ../public/index.html .;
```

setup routing:

```
# /path/to/meteor/server/bootstrap.js
Router.route('/', {
  where: 'server'
}).get(function() {
  var contents;
  contents = Assets.getText('index.html');
  return this.response.end(contents);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out through some trial and error. Thanks to @quirk for pointing me in the right direction. also, `console.log(fs.readdirSync('.'))`

The path to the "/public" folder in a meteor-up deployment is:

`// console.log(fs.readdirSync('.')) => '/opt/my-app/current/bundle/programs/server'
public_folder = '../../programs/web.browser/app'
filepath = '../../programs/web.browser/app/index.html'`

Answer (score 0):

You gave the answer yourself in the question. You just need to have the correct URL depending on your deployment status (development or production). Just set a new environment variable in your `mupx` config file and look for it in `process.env` before your generate your URL for `index.html`.

---

Aside from the fact that the above is a quick and dirty hack to resolve your problem, I feel that you are approaching this in entirely the wrong way. If `index.html` needs to be your default page when you visit the site (yes that is what the route '/' is equivalent to), why is it not your `client/main.html`.

If for some reason unbeknownst to us, you cannot use the client folder, just keep a `main.html` in your project root and set it up to redirect to `/index.html` using a simple HTML redirect. What is the need to stone cold generate your own page response?!

Comment: You are right, this is hack-ish. But I'm trying to deploy and 'ionic CLI' webapp on the same domain as the Meteor backend. If there is a better way, then please share. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881148/how-can-i-rewrite-redirect-the-default-page-in-meteor-to-point-to-public-index. But I'm not clear about how to use the environment variable to get the filepath of the '/public' folder.

Comment: You just look for a specific environment variable (say `PROD`). You define it in your `mupx` config file so that is shows up in your production server's environment variables. In your code you check for the variable. If it exists, then you can use a different hard-coded URL than the one you use for your development server. Your custom environment variable doesn't need to have any useful value whatsoever. It just needs to be declared so that you can find it later. It just serves similar to a `boolean` flag.